# Magento v1.9.x ultimate module creator entity URL rewrite / key problem

Tags: magento-1.9, url-rewrite, magento-community, product-urls

Hi all ( especially Marius :) )

I have an annoying problem with my **Mag 1.9.x** modules created using the, otherwise great, ultimate module creator.  When an item/entity is given a friendly URL and initially saved then all is great.  However, if the item/entity is reloaded, edited in some way and saved then the friendly URL (unchanged) is seen as a duplicate of the existing URL and then appends -1, -2, -3....and so on for each save.  This then means the proper/original URL no longer works and the URL changes with each edit.  It is possible to go back and then remove the -1 (or whatever number it has reached) as the original no longer exists as a URL.

It seems that this might not be specific to UMC modules but any entity types that are not products, categories or otherwise inbuilt to Magento.  I wondered if there was a known fix for this as I am already fiddling with overwriting the core to check if the found matching url actually belongs to the same item as you are currently saving so not to update it but it is proving troublesome and seems to impact quite a lot of things.

Thanks
Jon

Comment: This extension is discontinued.

Comment: Yer I know but it has proved helpful as a basis to get things going sometimes.

Comment: If it's worth something, I could not reproduce this on my side on CE

Comment: Interesting, was that with multi-store EAV structure or flat out of curiosity?  Thanks for taking the time out to take a look Marius.

Comment: both, eav and flat. But I checked on M1 CE 1.9.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is not related to UMC, since it is a known core bug.

Magento has never released a patch for CE, however a Patch for Enterprise Edition has been leaked (**SUPEE-389**). You may find lots of gists like this one

https://gist.github.com/piotrekkaminski/c348538ca91ba35773be

it is about the class `Mage_Catalog_Model_Url`

affected methods are

```
getUnusedPath()
getUnusedPathByUrlkey()
```

Comment: That gist looks interesting.  I have noticed the problem in my own modules also.  It is particularly annoying when a url ends with a number like  some-stuff-2018   ... which then becomes some-stuff-2019 which is not very helpful  :)

Comment: it also gains growth of core_url_rewrite table and indexing becomes slower

Answer (score 1):

This module might help you https://github.com/vladsmirnov/url-rewrites. I have used it in one of my projects. It helped in reducing the duplicates while reindexing.

Please run the shell script in the module to remove the duplicates in your current instance.

As always it is suggested, please take a backup of your database and install the module.

Comment: Hey Kaylan, I will take a look at this.  it isn't the fact that I have duplicates as such but that may well be useful

Comment: Hi Jon, how are duplicates useful?

Comment: they are from SEO point of view. Linkpower will be lost if redirect chain breaks at some point. Also GWT will show lots of Crawling Issues

Comment: Yes I didn't mean the duplicates were necessarily but that the module linked to might be useful :)

Comment: :) ok got it now